# wrong value from MYSQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

when running this query in phpMyAdmin, I get the correct values,
but when using the same line in a PHP script, 
It always gives x=0 y=0.

All other values are correct only x and y
for some reason return 0.

**EDITED** not getting the right values

code:

```
$sql = "select a.image_id as id, 
 i.image_url as url, 
 i.image_x as x,
 i.image_y as y 
from album a 
join images i 
 where a.album_id = 1 
and 
 i.image_id = a.image_id";

echo getFunc($sql); 

function getFunc($sql) {
 try {
    $db = getConnection();
    $stmt = $db->query($sql);
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $db = null;
    return json_encode($result);
 } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
 }
};                      
function getConnection() {
  $dbhost="127.0.0.1";
  $dbuser="root";
  $dbpass="";
  $dbname="efrattest";
  $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
  $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $dbh->exec("set names utf8");
  return $dbh;
}
```

mySQL table:

```
image_id    int(11)          
image_url   varchar(250)             
image_x int(9)       
image_y int(9)
```

Comment: is $sql defined? We cannot tell in this example as there is a stray select query

Comment: As Ray points out, is $sql defined? Is $album_id correctly defined?

Comment: Sorry guys I edited the question.
Anything else that is wrong with it?

Comment: You forgot the `;` after the first line... (Where you do your `$sql = [...]`)

Comment: indeed Marty, that's because of copy/pasting.
the code is good, nothing wrong except for the values returned

Comment: Can you supply some of the data in the db and the result JSON you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everybody,
the problem lays at

```
$dbhost="127.0.0.1";
```

I changed that from 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' 
as it was supposed to be better with PDO (A tip I heard online)

changed it back to 'localhost' now everything works as it should.